Filter and sort data using formulas only
I would like to filter and sort data using formulas only in Excel 2016.
Look the images below to see I would like the code process to get all the results I want.
I have a table with a lot of data in my sheet TABLE, it is my data base.
First step

In the sheet DATA, I paste some entries and I would like my WorkBook to update automatically with formulas and filter my table with data I put in the first sheet and get the filter result in the second sheet. I want to change the column order and sort the new table with the column called Table5.
Enter data

Filter and sort table

Then, I want to have another filter result in the sheet RESULTS depending on which entries I have, sorting by Table5's column, no duplicate and eventually concatenate Table6 and Table7 data as shown below.
Results

Hope it is clear and thank you.
Regards

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I think Power Query is a good option - please let me know after giving it a try:  Create Power Query formulas in Excel - Microsoft Support Download Microsoft Power Query for Excel from Official Microsoft Download Center
